# Django project has an internal 'lib' folder that has all Independence. How can i use .bash_profile project link dependencies

Tags: python, django, linux, bash, python-2.7

I have a Django 1.2 web app.  It uses python 2.7 and has very old libraries.  The project has a folder called 'lib' and 'webapp_extras" that have all the dependicnes.  But when i run it, it gives the following error:

```
File main.py, line , in <module>
     from google.appengine.ext import db
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

How can i tell the project to look in the 'lib' or project root for the dependencies?

So far i have tried to use a .bash_profile and set $PYTHONPATH to try and make it look in the correct 
folder.

```
/.bash_profile
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/<path to root folder>/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Am i doing something wrong?  Also i tried to pip install all the dependencies and it gives me an error when i try to install google-appengine

```
pip install google-appengine
#main error
"HTTP Error 403: SSL is required"
```

## Edit

Exact Error Message with print(sys.path)

```
        ['/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app', 
    '/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app', 
    '/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app/webapp2_extras/appengine', 
    '/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noah-app/lib', 
    '/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noah-app', '/usr/lib/python2.7', 
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
    '/home/vicktree/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
            from google.appengine.ext import db
        ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

Comment: That leading $ sign was a miss type, thanks. i am running "source ~/.bash_profile" from the terminal in Pycharm

Comment: If `google.appengine` is in `/path/to/root/lib/google/appengine`, then you need `/path/to/root/lib/` in the Python path. Maybe you need to adjust the line to something like `PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/<path to root folder>/:/home/<path to root folder>/lib:/home/<path to root folder>/webapp_extras"`. You can add `import sys; print(sys.path)` to your code to check that the lines in `.bash_profile` are changing the python path as expected.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not familiar with import sys.  I add that on the top of the program i am executing and it will return what?

Comment: Add that inside your Python/Django code, before the import which is failing.

Comment: it is printing out all the paths, but still says "n module named google.appengine.ext." Do you perhaps its another issue

Comment: Your approach of setting `PYTHONPATH` looks correct. I can't help any more without seeing the actual project layout, error message and result of `print(sys.path)`.

Comment: thanks for the help, i posted the exact error message

Comment: And where is `google.appengine.ext.db` that you are trying to import?